# preventing 12_db_migration.sh from executing during elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ruby on rails app (ruby 2.2.3 / rails 4.2.3 / puma) that is being deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk, which doesn't require a DB.

I somehow was able to trick AWS EB once to deploy successfully without a DB, but when trying to deploy again with new updates, I receive this response:

```
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I understand it fails because I do not have a production server set nor have the pg of sqlite3 gem in the Gemfile on purpose. What I'd like to do is completely skip the 12_db_migration.sh command.

Is this possible and does anyone know how to do it?

I assume it involves the .ebextensions folder / *.config file, but I'm not sure what the commands are and have scoured the internet with no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved via this post http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git adding the following commands into the *.config file

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS
    value: true
```